# Laravel dd command required parameter shows up empty

Tags: laravel, parameters

I'm trying to show one company from a list of companies but when i'm click on a company it will go to the right page but shows up empty(company has no attributes)

My route:

```
Route::resource('Companies',App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController::class);
```

My view(companies)

```
<div class="card-body  ">
<ul>

    @forelse($companies as $Company)


        <li>
            <a href="{{route('Companies.show',$company)}}">
                <label>Name: {{$company->name}}</label><br>
                <label>Name: {{$company->email}}</label><br>
                <label> Phone: {{$company->phone}}</label>
            </a>
        </li>


    @empty
        <h2>Companies</h2>
    @endforelse
</ul>
```

My Controller:

```
    public function show(Company $company)
{
    dd($company);
}
```

Output of dd:

```
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
```

Could someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: `{{route('companies.show',$company->id)}}` ?

Comment: please run `php artisan route:list` to make sure the route parameter for that route is named `company` as if it doesn't match **exactly** (even case) it will not do the route model binding and you will end up with dependency injection instead which would be a new empty instance of the model

Comment: in your loop you have written `$Company` with capital C, but you are using $company inside the loop, is it a typo here or in your code as well?

Comment: hey alex, 
the company->id gives the same error.

my output from php artisan route:list:

`GET|HEAD  | Companies/{Company}       | Companies.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@show`

the capital c was a typo tried both (lower and upper case c both giving the same error.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="{{route('companies.show', ['Company' => $company->id)}}">
```

Comment: Could you add some context to this so that "Could someone tell me why this happens?" is answered? Also, could this be an adaptation of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829948/laravel-dd-command-required-parameter-shows-up-empty/64834758#comment114622646_64829948) by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482904/alex)?